# possible lossy conversion from int to short but I have no int variable

Tags: types, type-conversion, integer, compiler-warnings, short

I was writing a code to print out the reverse of the 4-digit numbers, so my maximum number is 9999 and below 32767(maximum value of short) . The code is :

```
public class Project2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (short i = 1000; i <= 9999; i++){
            short rev = 0;
            short temp = i;
            while (temp != 0){
                rev = rev * 10 + temp % 10;
                temp /= 10;
            }
            System.out.println(rev);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why but I'm getting compile error which mentions :possible lossy conversion from int to short
and it shows 7th line for the error:
rev = rev * 10  $$$+$$$ temp % 10;
#error pointer is under the plus sign#

But when I convert shorts to ints it'll be ok
But why am I getting an error with short?My numbers are well under the maximum value of short
by the way I have no int variable to have convertion issue